# Table API's Over aggregation delays firing the trigger

Tags: apache-flink

Below is the code snippet：

```
// Firstly the inputStream receives the first batch of 420 records; 
// Secondly the inputStream receives the second batch of 420 records.
Table inputTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(
    inputStream, 
  Schema.newBuilder()
      .columnByExpression("rowtime", "CAST(eventTime AS TIMESTAMP(3))")
      .watermark("rowtime", "rowtime")
      .build());

tableEnv.createTemporaryView("InputTable", inputTable);

Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
    "SELECT " +
    " userId," +
    " eventTime," +
    " AVG(valueA) OVER w1 AS AVG_VALUE" +
    " FROM InputTable " +
    " WINDOW w1 AS (" +
    " PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY rowtime" +
    " RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '10' SECOND PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)"
);

DataStream<Row> resultStream = tableEnv.toDataStream(resultTable);

resultStream.map((Row row) -> {
  LOG.warn("Print row: " + row.toString()); 
  // In response to the inputSteam's first batch of 420 records the resultStream only receives 69 records; 
  // In response to the inputSteam's second batch of 420 records it receives additional 324 records.

  return row;
})
```

The issue looks like below:

1. Firstly the inputStream receives the first batch of 420 records - the interval between the records is 1 second;
2. In response to the inputSteam's first batch of 420 records the resultStream only receives 69 records;
3. Secondly the inputStream receives the second batch of 420 records;
4. In response to the inputSteam's second batch of 420 records the resultStream receives additional 324 records.

Need a solution to make the resultStream to retrieve query result in real-time.
I suppose that under the hood there is a trigger which fires the trigger for the SQL execution. Any idea how to customize/control it? Or what is the algorithm of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OVER window will be triggered for a particular row when these conditions are met:

1. there's an earlier row for that same userId that's at least 10 seconds older
2. the watermark has advanced up to the rowtime of that row (which will require seeing at least one row for rowtime+1)

All pending windows will be triggered at the end of the run if you execute it in batch mode, or with bounded streams.

Update:

With out-of-sequence records, you need accurate watermarking. As it is, out-of-sequence records are being dropped because they are late.

For example, if the records can be up to 15 seconds out of order, then specify the watermarking as

```
  WATERMARK FOR rowtime AS rowtime – INTERVAL ‘15’ SECOND
```

Comment: David Thanks

Trying to understand your comment. PartI: "All pending windows will be triggered at the end of the run if you execute it in batch mode".

In reality the inputStream will be fed with out-of-sequence records. To have correct calculation it is preferred to hold a window until the records of past 10 seconds arrive.

Do you mean I can achieve this by specifying batch mode only like below?
No other changes are needed?

StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

Comment: I think your problem is the watermarking -- see my updated answer. But yes, switching to batch mode should also help, and yes, that's how to do it. Or it can be specified when you submit the job (rather than in your code).

Comment: Thanks David. I tested BATCH mode and it seems to work. Will try the water mark strategy you mentioned. I have never specified the watermark directly with tableAPI. The reason I specified the Batch mode in code is because I am using AWS KDA. Have not figured out where to update the config of execution.runtime-mode